# How to set array document into redis in Golang?

Tags: arrays, go, redis

I have a problemwhen insert document in to redis.

I have a struct of data in Go:

```
type ArticleCovers struct {
    ID             int
    Covers         ArticleCovers
    ArticleTypeID  int
    Address        Address     `gorm:"ForeignKey:AddressID"`
}
```

I want to add a data like this into Redis:

```
[ID:1 Cover:[http://chuabuuminh.vn/UserImages/2012/12/10/1/chinh_dien_jpg.jpg] ArticleTypeID:1 Address:map[Street: City:<nil> District:<nil> DistrictID:0 ID:0 Slug: Lat:0 Long:0 Ward:<nil> WardID:0 CityID:0]]
```

But when I run `Redis.HMSet("test", structs.Map(ret))` it return the error: `redis: can't marshal postgresql.ArticleCovers (consider implementing encoding.BinaryMarshaler)`.

Who can help me fix my problem, thks you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the error message says, you need to implement the [`BinaryMarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#BinaryMarshaler) interface for your `ArticleCovers` type:

```
type ArticleCovers struct {
    ID             int
    Covers         ArticleCovers
    ArticleTypeID  int
    Address        Address     `gorm:"ForeignKey:AddressID"`
}

func (ac ArticleCovers) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v-%v", ac.ID, ac.ArticleTypeID)), nil
}
```

Note that this only adds the `ID` and `ArticleTypeID` fields. I don't know what
the `ArticleCovers` and `Address` types look like, but often you want to call
the same methods on that:

```
func (ac ArticleCovers) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {
    covers, err := ac.Covers.MarshalBinary()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    address, err := ac.Address.MarshalBinary()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v-%v-%v-%v",
        ac.ID, ac.ArticleTypeID, covers, address)
}
```

I don't know if this format makes sense for your data. You may want to use a
defined encoding format such as json.

You will probably also want to implement the `BinaryUnmarshaler` interface.
Doing that is left as an exercise ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As Carpetsmoker was saying about the JSON encoding this is how to do it:

```
func (ac ArticleCovers) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {
  return json.Marshal(ac)
}
```

Where when decoding you'd use [BinaryUnmarshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#BinaryUnmarshaler)

You can checkout for better example here at my [blog post](https://medium.com/@nevio/proper-way-how-to-marshal-and-unmarshal-golang-structs-within-the-redis-cache-855423902787)

Answer (score 0):

When saving any kind of object into redis directly, it tries to binary hash it so you should implement `MarshalBinary` to make it work. the idea is to save the value simply in a binary format or string format that is handled by the client internally.

So with that being said, one possible and easy solution of saving objects is save them in a string format, you can still use different marshaling techniques like `JSON` to do this.

```
func Save(obj interface{}) error {
  Redis.HMSet("test", json.Marshal(obj))
}
```

Although json is an easy way of doing this, but you can have better performance by using binary instead of text-based encoding. [gop](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) is package where it can encode and decode objects. also [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) is now widely used especially in such cases where we have different languages and integrations.

Here is a simple [example](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) with `gop` and `MarshalBinary`